# Jaspersoft Studio NullPointer connecting to Repository

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jasperserver, jaspersoft-studio

I am trying to connect the new *JasperSoft Studio Version 5.5* to the repository of my *JasperReports Server 4.5.0*. After entering all of the details and clicking test I am presented with the following *Nullpointer Exception*:

```java
AxisFault faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException faultSubcode: faultString:
java.lang.NullPointerException faultActor: faultNode: faultDetail:
{http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:java.lang.NullPointerException at
org.apache.axis.transport.http.CommonsHTTPSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPSender.java:193) at
org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32) at
org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118) at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83) at
org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165) at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784) at
org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767) at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443) at
org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366) at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812) at
com.jaspersoft.ireport.jasperserver.ws.RepositorySoapBindingStub.list(RepositorySoapBindingStub.java:339) at
com.jaspersoft.ireport.jasperserver.ws.WSClient.getVersion(WSClient.java:155) at
com.jaspersoft.studio.server.protocol.soap.SoapConnection.getServerInfo(SoapConnection.java:29) at
com.jaspersoft.studio.server.protocol.soap.SoapConnection.connect(SoapConnection.java:39) at
com.jaspersoft.studio.server.protocol.ProxyConnection.connect(ProxyConnection.java:24) at
com.jaspersoft.studio.server.WSClientHelper.connect(WSClientHelper.java:63) at
com.jaspersoft.studio.server.WSClientHelper.connectGetData(WSClientHelper.java:87) at
com.jaspersoft.studio.server.ServerProvider.listServer(ServerProvider.java:329) at
com.jaspersoft.studio.server.ServerProvider.access$0(ServerProvider.java:325) at
com.jaspersoft.studio.server.ServerProvider$1.run(ServerProvider.java:278) at
org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54) {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:MtwAtr1
java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.axis.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:101) at
org.apache.axis.transport.http.CommonsHTTPSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPSender.java:315) at
org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32) at
org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118) at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83) at
org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165) at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784) at
org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767) at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443) at
org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366) at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812) at
com.jaspersoft.ireport.jasperserver.ws.RepositorySoapBindingStub.list(RepositorySoapBindingStub.java:339) at
com.jaspersoft.ireport.jasperserver.ws.WSClient.getVersion(WSClient.java:155) at
com.jaspersoft.studio.server.protocol.soap.SoapConnection.getServerInfo(SoapConnection.java:29) at
com.jaspersoft.studio.server.protocol.soap.SoapConnection.connect(SoapConnection.java:39) at
com.jaspersoft.studio.server.protocol.ProxyConnection.connect(ProxyConnection.java:24) at
com.jaspersoft.studio.server.WSClientHelper.connect(WSClientHelper.java:63) at
com.jaspersoft.studio.server.WSClientHelper.connectGetData(WSClientHelper.java:87) at
com.jaspersoft.studio.server.ServerProvider.listServer(ServerProvider.java:329) at
com.jaspersoft.studio.server.ServerProvider.access$0(ServerProvider.java:325) at
com.jaspersoft.studio.server.ServerProvider$1.run(ServerProvider.java:278) at
org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at
org.apache.axis.transport.http.CommonsHTTPSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPSender.java:193) ... 20 more
```

Does anyone know if this is a version compatibility error or simply a file I need to edit to get it to connect.

P.S I have managed to get the *Jaspersoft Studio* to connect to my *JR Server version 5.2.0* without any errors.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is causing the error. But, you will want your versions of Studio and Server to match. Specifically, you want the JRLibrary versions to match. Otherwise you risk creating reports (in Studio) that are not supported on the server.